# Send data back to the script which started the activity via adb shell am start

Tags: android, bash, adb

I want to install a diagnostic app from `adb` and get back data from it from within a bash script. I know how to start an activity from `adb`, but I can't find any way to get data back unless maybe if I print to `logcat` and parse the output, but that sounds like a hack. Is there a way to receive data back from an activity started using `adb`?

Comment: Printing to logcat and then parsing for the result is not a hack

Comment: @AlexP. Okay, in that case can you or anyone tell me how to open logcat and wait for a result? If I run `logcat -d` immediately after `am start` the output will not be there yet, and I'd rather not guess how long the process will take to start.

Comment: just use `am start -W`

Comment: parsing logcat is a really bad approach!

Comment: @Paschalis, you are entitled to your opinion. But most likely you just do not know how to do it properly.

Comment: What kind of *diagnostic app* do you want to install? How could *back data* be transmitted from the app? Could you run this app *from* adb?

Comment: @AlexP. I found logcat not to be reliable in some extreme scenarios. If you send bursts of data in quite short amount of time, then you might lose a few lines.

Comment: @Paschalis, you were doing it wrong. If done properly there is 0 chance of losing any data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the data that you want to send back to your automation script could be serialized into a string less than 4k long - using `logcat` is a natural choice.
Just make your activity to print the data to the log with `Log.i("UNIQUE_TAG", the_data_string_you_want_to_send_back_to_your_script);` and then use the following commands in your automation script to capture the output:

```
# clear the logcat buffer
adb logcat -c

# start your activity
adb shell am start <INTENT>

# this line will block until a string with "UNIQUE_TAG" tag and "Info" priority
# is printed to the main log
adb shell 'logcat -b main -v raw -s UNIQUE_TAG:I | (read -n 1 && kill -2 $((BASHPID-1)))'

# now you can capture the data and process it
DATA=$(adb logcat -d -b main -v raw -s UNIQUE_TAG:I)
```

In more recent Android versions (7.0+) where `logcat` properly supports `-m <count>`, `-t <time>` and `-T <time>` parameters you can use this much simpler version without having to clear the log with `logcat -c` first:

```
# instead of clearing the log just get the current timestamp
TS=$(adb shell 'echo $EPOCHREALTIME; log ""')

# start your activity
adb shell am start <INTENT>

# this command will return immediately if the data has been printed already or block if not
DATA=$(adb shell "logcat -b main -T $TS -m 1 -v raw -s UNIQUE_TAG:I")
```