# Sending data from an Android Activity to PC through ADB

Tags: android, android-activity, tcp, adb

Is it possible to send data from an android Activity to adb ? I want to start an activity through ADB and pass it some data, perform an operation, then read the result. 
What is the best way to do this ?

For example:
adb.exe shell am start -n com.example/com.example.Adder --ei operand1 10 --ei operand2 20
This adds 10 + 20 .. and stores the total 30. How do I fetch that value ?

These suggestions from my research are not an option:
1. write to a file then read it from adb using pull [the phone my not have an SD card, and there is a bug with android 4.3 that means run-as command doesnt work]
2. opening a socket and sending data through that [I dont want to depend on a network]

UPDATE: 
so I have been able to do something through adb forward as Chris suggested.
I first start the adb forward:
adb forward tcp:10000 tcp:10000;

Then on my android application.. I create a server socket and block at
serverSocket.accept();
Then the client connects.. and then you can send data back and forth as you would with TCP/IP socket.

I just have one issue now, which is not documented in ADB; once the forward is setup, the client seems to connect to the server socket even if it is not setup yet on the android side. 
Why is that the case, is it possible to detect that the serverSocket is not setup yet.. once my clientSocket connects to this "shadow" socket ??

Comment: Using a socket could be done via adb forwards rather than a network.  Using a unix domain socket even avoids the need for internet permission. With adb forwards the phone must be the server and the pc the client, but that can be used to fill your needs by trying repeatedly to connect from shortly after sending the start intent via adb.  For something trivial you can also just log it and grep the answer out of logcat.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this more. From my activity, I can do: "            server = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
Socket client = server.accept();
PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
pr .print(dataToWrite); how would this be forwarded to adb ? If the phone is the Server, then at what point will accept() return ??

Comment: Read the ADB documentation.

Comment: ADB docs really dont say much on forwarding.. there is two lines in there. But anyway, I am using thrift.. i Have a server on my computer, so that opens a socket and listens, the bridge is setup, on my phone, the activity connects to that socket, and attempts to write data. I am getting this error: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED

Answer (score 6):

I have a code that alredy do that, please read [my blog](http://androideazteca.blogspot.com/2013/06/pues-bien-parece-que-como-bloggero-me.html), is in spanish, but the code is a universal language :D

I use webSockets, a WebSocket server in Android device and a WebSocket client in a Web Page, via JavaScript.

Android device must be in USB debbuging mode, and you must execute 'adb forward tcp:38300 tcp:38300' in PC's command line to create the 'tunnel' that allow WebSocket connection.

Answer (score 4):

Have your application simply use the standard [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class, and using adb logcat to read the output, filtering for whatever you want to capture.

Comment: this simple approach works really well. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41512862/1778421

Answer (score 0):

There is not much documentation on the ADB forwarding, but I think what's happening is that ADB is not really tunneling traffic like you would expect from an SSH session. It's just staring a tcp listener on the PC and a tcp client on the device and sending data from one to the other. The downside is that the PC is always accepting connections on the forwarded port even if there is no Android app listening on that port.

Comment: Indeed, this was causing me an issue. I didnt really find a way to solve it, but I used thrift on top of TCP/IP and didnt have to worry about opening and closing sockets