# Interrupt logcat without leaving the bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, adb

I wrote a basic shell script with which I intend to cut the time required to do testing of my device.

My current issue is when I want to stop the execution of logcat, if I use the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> command, I kill the whole script.
I just wish for the script to loop back to the option menu.

I do need the logcat to constantly display the data, so `logcat -d` is not an option.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Select an option: '
options=("Restart ADB Server" "ABR Test" "Reboot the device" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Restart ADB Server")
            printf "\nRestarting the ADB Server...\n"
            adb disconnect
            adb kill-server
            adb start-server
            adb connect 192.168.1.100
            ;;
        "ABR Test")
            printf "\nStarting the ABR Test\n"
            clear
            adb logcat | grep onVideoInputFormatChanged --line-buffered
            ;;
        "Reboot the device")
            printf "\nRebooting the device...\n"
        adb reboot
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *)  printf "\n$REPLY is an invalid option!\n";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41512862/1778421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to catch the signal generated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (`SIGINT`) using the `trap` keyword (`trap <callback> <signal>`) and stop `logcat` from a callback function, something like this:

```
stop_logcat() {
    # stop logcat here
}

trap 'stop_logcat' SIGINT

# your code here
```

Documentation on [Traps](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html).