# Trigger Host from Android device

Tags: android, adb, android-espresso

I run my android test using Espresso framework. 
On one point of the running test, I need to trigger an audio file playback on host PC(to test speech recognition). Is there a way in Android, Espresso, adb, etc. where I can send a trigger message **from** the Android device **to** the host computer connected via adb ?
 I've googled for hours now, but I can not find any idea how do do that.
I'm thankful of any idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22844066/1778421

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send data back to the script which started the activity via adb shell am start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844066/send-data-back-to-the-script-which-started-the-activity-via-adb-shell-am-start)