# How to tail output from adb logcat and execute a command each new line

Tags: linux, bash, adb, logcat

I'm trying to do very likely to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12075/best-way-to-follow-a-log-and-execute-a-command-when-some-text-appears-in-the-log) but instead of reading from a file I want to "subscribe" to the output of `adb logcat` and every time a new line is logged I will run some code on this line.

I tried these codes, but none worked

```
tail -f $(adb logcat) | while read; do 
    echo $read;
    processLine $read;
done
```

or

```
adb logcat >> logcat.txt &
tail -f logcat.txt | while read; do 
    echo $read;
    processLine $read;
done
```

What is the simples way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22844066/1778421 has some pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two solutions should work. I generally prefer the second form as the wile loop is run in the current process and so I can use local variables.  The first form runs the while loop in a child process.

While loop in child process:

```
#!/bin/bash

adb logcat |
while read -r line; do
  echo "${line}"
  processLine "${line}"
done
```

While loop in current process:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  echo "${line}"
  processLine "${line}"
done < <(adb logcat)
```

Comment: Don't forget the option `-r` to the `read` command. And don't use variables outside of double quotes: `"$line"` (or `"${line}"` with the useless braces).

Comment: @syme: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have just got in the habit of ALWAYS enclosing variables in braces. This way, I can never mix two styles in one script.

Comment: using braces is a style ; using double quotes is not (without them, it leads to unexpected/unwanted results).

Comment: @syme. Agree about double quotes, which is why I made that change without commenting on it.

Comment: inotifywait is the tool for this.